# HTML5 button with more than one name/value pair

Tags: html, button

The name/value pair of a `<button>` element together with further parameters of the surrounding form are send to the server. But now I have a case where I have several buttons within a form, but for reasons of clean logic it would be nice to attach two parameters to some buttons. The alternatives I have

1. wrap a form around each of the buttons
2. encode the two parameters into one
3. use Javascript

would all work, but don't feel right. Is there an clean HTML way to attach two parameters to a `<button>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Each form should have exactly one submit button. If you have 2, you need to have 2 forms.
I don't think anything is cleaner than that :)

Comment: "IE6 has an even worse bug where submitting a form through a button will submit ALL buttons of the form" is said on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button. Albeit implicitly this means that a form can and may have many buttons.

Comment: Forget that word "IE6" it doesn't exist anymore :D I get goose bumps every time I hear it. So no need to worry about IE6.